# Issues with a published property of a large enum set

Tags: delphi, properties, enums

I'm creating a component with many published properties for the IDE, and one of such properties is an enum set with 38 values...

```
type
  TBigEnum = (beOne, beTwo, beThree, beFour, beFive, beSix, beSeven, beEight,
    beNine, beTen, beEleven, beTwelve, beThirteen, beFourteen, beFifteen,
    beSixteen, beSeventeen, beEighteen, beNineteen, beTwenty, beTwentyOne,
    beTwentyTwo, beTwentyThree, beTwentyFour, beTwentyFive, beTwentySix,
    beTwentySeven, beTwentyEight, beTwentyNine, beThirty, beThirtyOne,
    beThirtyTwo, beThirtyThree, beThirtyFour, beThirtyFive, beThirtySix,
    beThirtySeven, beThirtyEight);
  TBigEnums = set of TBigEnum;
```

Now, I try to use this in a component as a published property...

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FBigEnums: TBigEnums;
  published
    property BigEnums: TBigEnums read FBigEnums write FBigEnums;
  end;
```

But the compiler does not let me...

```
[DCC Error] MyUnit.pas(50): E2187 Size of published set 'BigEnums' is >4 bytes
```

I understand this limitation, but how can I get around this without splitting it into two different sets?

PS - Each of these values actually has a unique name and purpose, but for the sake of example I just used the number as their names.

Comment: This enum set actually represents all the possible `flags` in an Inno Setup script `[Files]` section. There are 38 possible flags, so I put 38 enum values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember the exactly correct syntax but in principle:

**1** If the "property" does not have to be easily editable in the property inspector then definining 38 different **consts** of type Long with their values set to `1 shl 0, 1 shl 1, 1 shl 2..`

so that those consts can be combined like this `PropOne or PropTwo or PropThree`

**2** if the property must be editable in the property inspector then the `TMyPersistent` class proposed in Jerry's answer seems ok to me

**3** there might be a way built-into the language (or compiler directive) how to type-cast the set representation so that it uses 8 bytes for storage. Int32 and Int64 are both native data types well supported on new processors and both assembler, C++ and C# can deal with it.
Some Pascal flavor (Free Pascal?) either has it implemented or it was in the road map

**EDIT** option **3** seems to be misleading. What can Free Pascal compiler do regarding enums is listed here http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/prog.html, especially in chapter `$PACKENUM`. As of today enums are always backed by 32bit [ordinals](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu5.html). So the possibility to increase number of bits used for "enums" possible in assembler, C++, C# is not likely to be available in Delphi.

I'm not even sure if bitwise operators `and, or, not, shl, shr` used in other languages to implement enums and sets are available for 8-byte integers either in Delphi or in Free Pascal so the option **1** might also be misleading and the winner is option **2**